# Evaluate the given integral...

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the given integral
$$\int \dfrac {3}{x^3-1} dx$$

I didn't get any idea. Please help

Comment: You can factor the denominator. Does partial fraction decomposition help?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{3}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+x+1} \implies A = 1,\ B=-1, \ C = -2$$

Answer (score 1):

MPW already gave the hint for *partial fraction decomposition*:
$$\frac{3}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+x+1}$$

Here by comparing coefficients of powers of $x$ you can find $A,B,C$. Now integration is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use a variant of  partial fraction decomposition

$$\dfrac3{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}=\dfrac A{x-1}+\dfrac{B(2x+1)+C}{x^2+x+1}$$

$\implies3=A(x^2+x+1)+(x-1)[B+C+2Bx]$

$3=x^2(A+B)+x(A+B+C-2B)+A-B-C$

Comparing the coefficients of $x,x^2$ and the constants,

$A+B=0,A-B+C=0,A-B-C=3$

$\implies B=-A, C=B-A=-2A$

$3=A-B-C=A+A-(-2A)\iff A=?$

Comment: It's faster giving specific values ro $x$

Comment: @Bernard, I think you are referring $x-1=0$ and that would give the value of $A$ only

Comment: You also have $x=j$, which gives $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \dfrac {3}{x^3-1} = \dfrac {1}{x-1} - \dfrac {x+2}{x^2+x+1}=  \dfrac {1}{x-1} - \dfrac {x+1/2}{x^2+x+1}  - \dfrac {3/2}{x^2+x+1} =\\ \left(\ln(x-1) - \frac12\ln(x^2+x+1)\right)'- \frac32\dfrac {1}{(x+1/2)^2+3/4}$$

The last term is an arctan after integration. It suffices to use the change of variables $u= \sqrt{3}/2(x+1/2)$